# QImage from file content

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a table in my DB which contains information about images (like width, height, content-type, file-type and file content). In column `file_content` stored entire image (not pixel data or something else - entire file readed and stored as binary data). Now I want to create QImage (or QPixmap) from this record in my application on Python+PySide. How can I do it?

I tried loadFromData, but it is expects raw pixel data, not file with header like in my case.

Actually, I have no idea hot to solve it.

UPD: My code sample which does not works:

```
    with open('Koala.jpg', 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()

    self.image = QtGui.QImage()

    print self.image.loadFromData(content)
```

Result:

```
False
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
JPEG datastream contains no image
```

Comment: loadFromData should work, it doesn't expect raw pixel data.  Are you giving it the right image format?  Have you confirmed that the data you're passing in does actually represent a valid image?

Comment: @DanMilburn I updated question with source code which does not works for me. No matter what kind of image - jpg or png I trying to load it always fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a silly mistake! Just replaced `with open('Koala.jpg', 'r') as f:` with `with open('Koala.jpg', 'rb') as f:` and `loadFromData` loaded my images.

Never forget to open image files as binary!

Answer (score 0):

There is `QImage::loadFromData` for that.

See the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#loadFromData).

Comment: Thank you for reference to C++ Qt, but for Python port Pyside existing only one method `loadFromData` (http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QImage.loadFromData) which returns `bool`. Anyway, it is not working accordingly to my updated waustion - I've added code sample.